# Django-RestFramework Custom Seriliazation

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have problem in custom serialization and I look in documentation for hours, but I couldn't figure out what I will do. I have nested serializers object like below but I want to have non-nested object, can anyone help me with this?

Nested Object:

```
{
    "id": 1,

    "adDate": "20-08-2016",
    "price": "30.50",
    "city": "Istanbul",
    "latitude": "28.987509",
    "longitude": "41.040353",
    "isPublished": true,
    "book": {
        "id": 1,
        "bookName": "GameOfThrones",
        "category": "Adventure",
        "photo": "http://localhost:8000/media/advert_images/game_of_thrones.jpg",
        "description": "Adventure Book",
        "author": "Emre Yavuz",
        "language": "Sangridce",
        "publicationDate": "2023",
        "publisher": "Deu_Yapim",
        "edition": "22",
        "page_number": 900
    }
}
```

Non-Nested Object:

```
{
    "id": 1,

    "adDate": "20-08-2016",
    "price": "30.50",
    "city": "Istanbul",
    "latitude": "28.987509",
    "longitude": "41.040353",
    "isPublished": true,


    "bookName": "GameOfThrones",
    "category": "Adventure",
     "photo": "http://localhost:8000/media/advert_images/game_of_thrones.jpg",
     "description": "Adventure Book",
     "author": "Emre Yavuz",
    "language": "Sangridce",
    "publicationDate": "2023",
    "publisher": "Deu_Yapim",
     "edition": "22",
     "page_number": 900

}
```

My Serializer Class:

```
class AdvertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   book = BookSerializer()

   class Meta(object):
       model = Advert
       fields = ('id', 'adDate', 'price',"city","latitude","longitude","isPublished",'book','seller')
       depth = 2
```

.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    photo = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None,use_url=True) 
    class Meta(object):
        model = Book
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would prefer a non-nested representation but in order to archive that, you need to specify book fields, one by one on your serializer using the `source` field attribute.

```
class AdvertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   book_name = serializer.CharField(source='book.bookName')
   description = serializer.CharField(source='book.description')
   # add the rest of the book fields in that way


   class Meta(object):
       model = Advert
       fields = ('id', 'adDate', 'price',"city","latitude","longitude","isPublished",'book','seller')
```